# How to Iterate json data in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am working on an Angular 6 project. In my project I am making a request through httpClient through which I am getting json data but I don't know how to iterate over this data. If anybody knows the solution please help.

My Json data look like:

[Json data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQR6r.png)

Error details:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKCSL.png)

app.component.js

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'servicedemo';
  private url = "http://localhost/api.php";
  public apps: Applications[];

constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    http.get(this.url).subscribe(result => {
        this.apps = result as Applications[];
        console.log(this.apps);
    }, error => console.error(error));
}}

interface Applications {
    id: number;
    name: string
    age: number 
}
```

app.componenet.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of apps">
    {{ item.name }}
 </div>
```

Comment: You are just mixing AngularJS with Angular 6. Did you try `*ngFor` instead of `ng-repeat`?

Comment: I have tried with *ngFor also but It did not work for me

Comment: What was the problem? Some error on console or only empty list?

Comment: plz check error image

Comment: The error says everything itself, the apps isn't an array, actually, it's an object.

Comment: so how can I iterate over the object?

Comment: If the Angular version is 6.1 or above, you can do:
`<div *ngFor="let item of apps | keyvalue">
  {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
</div>`

Comment: now result is: 0:[object Object]
1:[object Object]
3:[object Object]

Comment: thank you much, it's working :)

Comment: This is not angular related, because your response is object and you need to cast that object to array to be able to use *ngFor that way... try something like this ` Object.keys(response);` also api calls calls goes to service, so create service and inject it in your component class and then call method in service from your component. In service iterate on your object keys and return array of items

Comment: You're welcome @AjeetSingh. You can answer your question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

First use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on it to convert Object to Array:

```
    http.get(this.url).subscribe(result => {
        const arr: Applications[] = Object.keys(result);
        this.apps = arr;
        console.log(data);
    }, error => console.error(error));
```

Also you should subscribe in onInit